# Live draggable div - position, sorting weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I added elements to green div with button, then I want to drag them do red div. While dragging (just moving to the element red) it moves (or little jumps). Look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KzWkS/ and try it.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        $('#pridaj').click(function(){
             $("<div style='border:1px solid black; position: relative;padding:3px;margin:2px;width:190px;float:left;' class='keyword'>"+$('#newArea').val()+"</div>").appendTo('#green');
            $('#newArea').val('');

        });
         $('.keyword').live('mouseover',function(){
            $('.keyword').draggable({connectToSortable:'#red'});
         });
    });

     $(function() {
         $( "#red" ).sortable();
         $( "#red" ).disableSelection();
    });
```

And.. If I want to drag them back, it does these thing too...

Maybe there is a problem with positioning (absolute/relative), but I haven't found yet.

Comment: `$.live()` is deprecated and a terrible approach (by the jQuery dev team) to handling new element events. Use [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead, which you would put on an element that contains the element you're looking to catch.

Comment: Or in this situation, attach the `$.draggable()` on the `.keyword` when it's inserted on the `button` click.

Comment: I haven't fixed the jump problem yet, but see this fiddle for what I'm suggesting above: http://jsfiddle.net/KzWkS/1/

Comment: It's the sortable affecting the draggable. A `.ui-sortable-helper` class gets added and the style manipulated, which changes the styling and shifts the way the `.keyword` draggable displays. Haven't figured out yet what to do, but here is where I am at: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KzWkS/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep adding the .draggable just make your green and red as sortable columns and link them.

I tried condensing this down and doing it a slightly different way.

BTW it helps to keep your CSS seperate and not inline.  It will help to keep things easier to read, maintain and change.

```
<style type="text/css">  
    #pridaj {
        border:1px solid gray;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 2px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }      
    #green, #red {
        margin: 2px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        height:100px;
        width:200px;
    }
    #green {
        background: green;
    }
    #red {
        background: #ff9999;
    }
    .keyword {
        border:1px solid black;
        position: relative;
        padding:3px;
        margin:2px;
        width:190px;
        float:left;
    }
</style> 

<input type='text' id='newArea'/><button id='pridaj'>pridaj kluc slovo</button><br />
<div id='green' class="sortable"></div>
<div id='red' class="sortable"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable"
    });

    $('#pridaj').click(function() {
        $("<div class='keyword'>" + $('#newArea').val() + "</div>").appendTo('#green');
        $('#newArea').val('');

    });

});           
</script>
```

Comment: Does it work? You've got a shorthand `$(document).ready()` within a `$(document).ready()`, so I wonder if it will run at all. However, it's the sortable itself which is causing the problem. So I wonder if the way you've done that will fix the issue or not.

Comment: thanks, fixed the redundancy.  But yes, it does work.  Check http://jsfiddle.net/KzWkS/4/

Comment: It's actually a specific type of draggable and droppable functionality. See: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable The issue is related to the fact you're supposed to use `helper: 'clone'` for it to work right. The problem, though, is you now have two in the green square...

Comment: Tims, it satisfied me. Thank you, great Idea!

Comment: But I have one more question, is it possible to handle moved object? Some like... pseudocode: `if (this).dropped do something...`

Comment: @user1666761 - I actually solved that problem, I just hadn't posted it yet.

Answer (score 1):

To take this a bit further and handle the dropped element you can adjust the above code to:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    receive : function(event, ui) {
        alert("You just dropped "+ui.item.context.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

Where you can do whatever you wish with the dropped item (in this case an alert stating the inner html) by refering to it using ui.item.whatever

it is also very helpful to use console.log(ui.item);

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeaah, great, it helped me very much!

Comment: That's cheating to a degree: There's no draggable, so sure, it's easy since there's no clone. I don't know if @user1666761 intended to use a draggable as well, but this doesn't "fix" the clone issue as much as it removes it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I worked out. Note, the demo below the code is slightly different, so you don't have to keep typing text into the input each time to test.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $red = $('#red'),
        $green = $('#green'),
        $pridaj = $('#pridaj'),
        $keyword = $('#keyword'),
        $keywords = $('<div class="keyword">');

    $red
        .disableSelection()
        .sortable({
            deactivate: helper,
            receive: helper
        });

    $pridaj.click(function(){
        $keywords
            .clone()
            .text($keyword.text())
            .appendTo($green)
            .disableSelection()
            .draggable({
                connectToSortable: $red,
                helper: "clone",
                revert: "invalid",
                start: helper,
                stop: helper
            });

        $keyword.one('focus', clear);
    });

    function clear() {
        this.value = '';
    }

    function helper(event, ui) {
        if (event.type == 'dragstart') {
            $(this).hide();
        }

        if (event.type == 'sortdeactivate') {
            $(ui.item).show();
        }

        if (event.type == 'dragstop') {
            $(this).filter(':hidden').remove();
        }
    }

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KzWkS/8/